# Externalized Spring OAuth2 configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, docker-compose, spring-oauth2

I have a Resource Server Spring boot app (i.e. @EnableResourceServer annotated class) with following **application.yml** that works perfectly:

```
...
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9100/oauth/user
...
```

But when I try to run my server as docker image (from a docker file) with environment vars it does not take into account my configuration. The server will still use config from application.yml

```
 (from my **docker-compose.yml** file)
...
 environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8999
      - SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_USER-INFO-URI=http://oauth-server:7777/oauth/user
...
```

Comment: try to use external IP instead of the service name *oauth-server*.

Comment: No it's not the issue since my server is sending request to url set in application.yml.
But what I want is to use the url specified as OS enviroment variable

Comment: Oh, try `SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_USERINFOURI`